# Relationship between Decimal, Hexadecimal, and Binary (Beginner)

Tags: number-systems

I was studying the conversion technique between Hexadecimal and Binary where

For 
example

> $4C2_{16} = 010011000010_{2}$

Can be done by substituting 4 bits for each Hexadecimal digit.

Why is it so easy to achieve this conversion to binary by combining a series of 4 bits to represent each Hexadecimal digit?

This obviously does not work for decimal to binary conversions, but I am not too sure why either.

For example

> $15_{10} ≠00010101_{2}$

Comment: It would work the same way for converting between base 10 and base 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion from $2$ to $16$ is simple since $16=2^4$ so every $4$ digits count for one digit.

Meanwhile, bases $10=2\cdot5,16=2^4$ don't have a pattern for exponents of $10$ and $16.$

[There is a way to convert bases, though.](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-convert-any-number-in-base-X-to-base-Y)